# Python how to change formatting of an input when calling a function a second time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to code this function so that it gets called twice. On the first time it is called, s should be a string 'JSON/image', and the second time it is called, s should be a different string 'second'. The goal is that so when the function is called the first time it will ask:
"Enter JSON/image file"
and the second time it should prompt
"Enter text/txt file"

```
def open_file(times):
    times_run = 0
    while times_run <1:
       file_name = input("Enter {} file: ".format(times))
       try:
           fp = open(file_name, 'r')
           times_run += 1
           return(fp)
       except:
           print("File not found")
```

Comment: That's great. What's your question?

Comment: why would you want this to be able to handled by the function? I'm struggling to see what you're trying to do here and why. For instance - what also happens if you've done the json input, the txt input and then call it again... is it now expecting txt again or should it error... and what if something that's called it for txt is getting to ready to call it json but something calls txt first again first?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure you understand the principles of file handling. You said the goal was to initially get a "Enter a JSON file" and a "Enter a txt file" message. However, your try and except handling isn't working correctly. You're printing "File not found. Try again", but there is no again. The code just stops working since there's no loop or recurrence. This is some code I think will be helpful:

```
s=('JSON', 'txt')

def check_json(s):
    file_name = input("Enter a {} file name: ".format(s[0]))
    try:
        fp = open(file_name, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found. Try again.")
    return check_json(s)
    
def check_txt(s):
    file_name = input("Enter a {} file name: ".format(s[1]))
    try:
        fp = open(file_name, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found. Try again.")
    return check_txt(s)

check_json(s)
check_txt(s)
```

You wanted a variable s even though it could've been done without that and without the format() method. It can obviously be done without functions as well.

I hope this clears things up in terms of changing the format of an input in a function

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure that you shouldn't do that! I guess you have control over calling it so you could just add extra parameter for your function and based on it decide whether is it JSON or TXT. Saying that, if you don't mind do some ugly things, you could use decorator:

```
def deco(fun):
    def f(s):
        f.no_calls += 1
        fun(s, f.no_calls)

    f.no_calls = 0
    return f


@deco
def open_file(s, no_calls): # no_calls parameter will be provided by decorator
    if no_calls == 1:
        print("JSON")
    if no_calls == 2:
        print("TXT")

# you call it without second parameter
open_file("") # JSON
open_file("") # TXT
```